# How to align Spring Boot context path with Apache Camel context path?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, contextpath

I to have a unified context path **/api/*** for all my RestControllers, as well as all of my Apache Camel Routes that are using rest.

For my understanding, these are the properties that are required to set:

```
camel.rest.api-context-path=/api/*
server.servlet.context-path=/api/*
camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/api/*
```

However, it seems they are somehow conflicting and I cannot get them working all together. It usually leads to 404 errors and none of the routes are accessible.

What do I have to do in order to make everything working under the same context path?

Comment: You cannot. Unless you put a filter in front which eventually dispatches to the proper part of your application. Or put camel behind spring instead of on the same level ( you can use a `ServletForwardingController` or `ServletWrappingController` for that.

Comment: I see. There is also the platformHttp API https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/platform-http-component.html .Would this automatically put Apache Camel behind the Spring context path as well?

Comment: I don't know, I have almost zero knowledge of Apache Camel.